# Cannot recover from suspend using mouse

Tags: unity, 20.04, suspend

Ubuntu 20.04

I use `unity 7.5.0` with `lightdm`

Till few updates ago,I could go to the lock screen of the suspended machine by moving the mouse.

However, now I cannot move mouse to go from suspend to the lock screen. Instead, I need to press keys on the keyboard. This is not ideal as some characters can be typed into the password field.

Is there any way to unsuspend the computer by moving mouse?

Comment: Why not use the SHIFT or CTRL key. They're usually easy to find (*even in the dark by feel*) and don't cause any keys to be entered into a password field.